# Maven android manage both android 2.2 and 3.0

Tags: android, maven, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-maven-plugin

Is there a way to manage a project that runs on Android 2.2 and >= and that uses specific Android 3.0 functionalities for 3.0 >= plateforms ?

I tried to set in the pom.xml

```
<sdk>
    <platform>11</platform>
</sdk>
```

And in the manifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

This kind of configuration works in Eclipse as I have the Android3.0.jar in the path. But it does not with Maven. Dependencies are not loaded since the compilation errors are about symbols "Fragments", "FragmentTransaction", etc... are not found.

So how could I configure my pom to take this into account ?

Here is my whole dependencies configuration, thanks a lot in advance.

```
<dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
    <artifactId>android</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-test</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>oauth.signpost</groupId>
    <artifactId>signpost-commonshttp4</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened an issue in the maven-android-plugin : [issue 188](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/issues/detail?id=188).

The first thing to do is to use the last version of [mosabua](https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer) to install the Android library in the local maven repository.

All the errors were correct but I still have a problem with the Activity#getFragmentManager() method that is not found at the compilation.

Comment: According to documentation of [the compatibility package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html)  Activity.getFragmentManager() must be replaced by FragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager(). Now everything works fine.